# Post a json body with swagger

Tags: json, rest, api, swagger, openapi

I would like to POST a json body with Swagger, like this :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d {"username":"foobar","password":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "email": "foo@bar.com"}' http://localhost/user/register
```

Currently, I have this definition :

```
"/auth/register": {
        "post": {
            "tags": [
              "auth"
            ],
            "summary": "Create a new user account",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "username",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "The username of the user",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "password",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "The password of the user",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "password"
                },
                {
                    "name": "email",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "The email of the user",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "email"
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "201": {
                    "description": "The user account has been created",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
                    }
                },
                "default": {
                    "description": "Unexpected error",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Errors"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the data are sent in the URL. Here the generated curl provided by Swagger :

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost/user/register?username=foobar&password=password&email=foo%40bar.com'
```

I understand that the `query` keywork is not good, but I didn't find the way to POST a JSON body. I tried `formData` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to use the `body` parameter:

```
    "parameters": [
      {
        "in": "body",
        "name": "body",
        "description": "Pet object that needs to be added to the store",
        "required": false,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        }
      }
    ],
```

and `#/definitions/Pet` is defined as a model:

```
"Pet": {
  "required": [
    "name",
    "photoUrls"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int64"
    },
    "category": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Category"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "doggie"
    },
    "photoUrls": {
      "type": "array",
      "xml": {
        "name": "photoUrl",
        "wrapped": true
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "type": "array",
      "xml": {
        "name": "tag",
        "wrapped": true
      },
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag"
      }
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "pet status in the store",
      "enum": [
        "available",
        "pending",
        "sold"
      ]
    }
  },
  "xml": {
    "name": "Pet"
  }
},
```

Ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.json#L35-L43

OpenAPI/Swagger v2 spec: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object

For OpenAPI v3 spec, `body` parameter has been deprecated. To define the HTTP payload, one needs to use the `requestBody` instead, e.g. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.json#L39-L41

OpenAPI v3 spec: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#requestBodyObject

Comment: How can I post "requestBody" using jquery ajax call or fetch?? I'm trying but swagger api receive params always empty

Comment: Please try openapi-generator to generate typescript-jquery, typescript-fetch clients and see if that's what you want.