# POST "try it out" does not work in Swagger 3.0 UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have set up a Swagger doc, and it looks OK in the UI. However, when I use the "try it out" functionality, I receive the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
```

The relevant part of my Swagger doc looks like this:

```
post:
      summary: Creates a new cinema
      operationId: addCinema
      consumes: [ application/json ]
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: body
          description: Name of the cinema
          schema:
            type: string
          example: "Bad cinema"
        - name: description
          in: body
          description: Description of the cinema
          schema:
            type: string
          example: "A pretty terrible cinema"
        - name: capacity
          in: body
          description: Capacity of the cinema
          schema:
            type: number
          example: 100
      responses:
        201:
          description: Creates the cinema
        400:
          description: 'Invalid request'
```

Any idea why I am seeing this error? I think maybe the body is sending HTML instead of JSON but I can't figure out why that would be?

Comment: Is your definition `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: Ah! It's actually `swagger: '2.0'` - what should it be?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Post a JSON body with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411628/post-a-json-body-with-swagger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is not valid, it has a mix of OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 keywords.

In OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`), there can be only one `in: body` parameter, and if the body is an object, the parameter `schema` should define the object structure.

So if your are POSTing this JSON:

```js
{
  "name": "foo",
  "description": "bar",
  "capacity": 100
}
```

your body parameter should look like:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: cinema
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
                example: Bad cinema
              description:
                type: string
                example: A pretty terrible cinema
              capacity:
                type: integer
                example: 100
```

or if you extract the inline schema into a named schema in `definitions`:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: cinema
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Cinema'

....

definitions:
  Cinema:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        example: Bad cinema
      description:
        type: string
        example: A pretty terrible cinema
      capacity:
        type: integer
        example: 100
```