# Describe file content in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm working on documenting our existing API's in swagger using open api 3.0.0 specification. I would like to understand the procedure on documenting the contents of a file that is to be uploaded. For e.g.

Say the file that is to be uploaded is response.json, and it has the following content:
{
 name: xyz,
 age: 50
}

I would like to know the procedure for documenting the above JSON so that clients using our API should provide the file in the aforesaid JSON format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post a JSON body with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411628/113116)

Comment: Thank you Helen. However, the post talks about URL encoded formats. I'm looking for documenting the file content.